# php shell commander login failed

Tags: php, linux, shell

I found this script:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/shcmd/

Unfortunately I can't login. I had a look at the code but can't figure out what is wrong. When starting this script the user has to type in the login name (e.g. "root") and the password. I use the server's login details the script is running on. I tried different combinations, such as "root", "root@[ip address]", "root@[domainname]". When using simple putty I can login this way but not with the mentioned script.
Do you have any idea what I did wrong?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you verified that the extensions proc_open() OR shell_exec() enabled on your server. Be sure to check this because a lot of servers are configured to disable these functions by default (for security reasons).